# Is it possible to set a image from a url into a pdf document with ZendPdf?

Tags: php, pdf, zend-framework, frameworks, zend-framework2

is it possible to set a image from a url into a pdf document with ZendPdf?

Thanks for help,
Mondy

Comment: Why not try and see if you can?

Comment: Yes, it is possible... you are welcome.